# Laravel update pivot table (many to many relationship)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have for tables named users, questions, answers and answer_user. I can get data from tables using $user->answers method but I couldn't figure out how to update or insert if not exists. (answer_user table)

**user table:**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('email', 255)->unique();
$table->string('password', 255);
```

**questions table:**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('title', 255);
```

**answers table:**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('text');
$table->integer('question_id')->unsigned();


$table->foreign('question_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('questions')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

**answer_user table**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('question_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('answer_id')->unsigned();


$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');

$table->foreign('question_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('questions')
      ->onDelete('cascade');

$table->foreign('answer_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('answers')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

**My models:**

```
class Question extends Model
{

    public function answer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }
}

class Answer extends Model
{

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }

}
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Answer');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-relationships). When you use attach, it will create some new rows in `answer_user` table. If you do not want this rows anymore, you can `detach` it. Or you can use `sync` when you want to add new rows and detach old rows in `answer_user` table (`sync` = `detach` + `attach` again)

```
class Question extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        //The question should belong to a user.
    }
    public function answers() 
    {
        //If you use hasMany, then the method should be plural nouns
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }
}

class Answer extends Model
{
    //One answer should belong to one question and one user 
    public function user()        
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 
    } 
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }

}
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function answers()
    {    
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }
}
```

If you want to use many to many relationship, you can imagine that one question belongs to many tags, and one tag has many questions. Then you can define it.

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question');
    }
}

class Question extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

If you want to have some relationships, you should define it in all tables.
Sorry because of my English.

Comment: Why it doesn't just update instead of adding new rows?

Comment: If you want to have any relationship betwen 2 table, you must add new rows. Or you can update it when the relationships exist

Comment: What do you mean by "update when relationship exist"? well I think I already have?

Comment: For example, you have a user with id 1, and the answer with id 1, if you want to create a relationship between those two, you must create a new row to show relationship, if not, it doesn't have any. If you did have some rows in answer_user (relationship), you can update it to change the relationships.

Comment: So how can I do it? $user->find(1)->answers()->attach($question_id, ['answer_id' => $answer_id]); fails and I can't pass the question id

Comment: I think $user->find(1)->attach('answer_id', $answer_id);

Comment: Because answer belong to question, you shouldn't attach it. You can attach an array too.

Comment: I think there must be a problem becouse question id is not passed to the query "General error: 1364 Field 'question_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `answer_user` (`answer_id`, `user_id`) values (3, 1))""

Comment: Did you add to $fillable array to prevent mass assignment?

Comment: How does it not which answer belongs to which question then? Because each question has different answers? Maybe you missed my table structure?

Comment: Yes I added it to the fillable

Comment: I think your relationships is not true. One user may has many answers, but one answer must to be belonged to one user.

Comment: Could you please give me code example of the correct relationship?

Comment: Please check my answer again.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. User::find(1)->answer returns null

Comment: My mistake, I edited it, please check again. Be sure that you added some record in answers table

Comment: I am getting Unknown column 'answers.user_id' right now. I have records in the tables

Comment: Because you don't need table answer_user anymore, then you must add user_id column into answer table.

Comment: My answers table stores answer options for the questions. Example: Question Hair Color and Answers column stores black, brown, etc... This way I can add questions and answers for th questions from my admin panel.

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstanded it. If you want to do in that case, you should use Many-to-Many relationship, because one answer belongs to many users, and one user belongs to many answers. Sorry because of that. But in this case you have to add questions and answers in database.

Comment: No problem. I already wrote that I have answers and questions tables in my database while asking my questions.

Comment: Then you should use `attach` and `sync` method to add some relationships in database. Good luck.